# Sequel Rails ODBC with Snowflake returns '\x1A' for special characters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, odbc, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, sequel

So I'm using Docker to run a Rails app which uses Sequel to connect to Snowflake via ODBC (`snowflake-odbc-2.22.4.x86_64.deb`). I'm able to connect to my Snowflake instance and query tables fine, but I'm currently running into an issue where any special characters is return `\x1A` instead of the character.
For example, if in Snowflake I have this table (`User`):
|fname|
|-|
|яйяйяй|

Running this query in Rails:
`SELECT fname FROM User`

returns

```
[{
:fname => "\x1A\x1A\x1A\x1A\x1A\x1A"
}]
```

where there's 1 `\x1A` for each special character

Doing `data[:fname].encoding` returns `ASCII-8BIT` and `data[:fname].force_encoding('UTF-8')` returns an empty string.

I did a similar query with python and the snowflake connector, and it worked fine, so this makes me think there might be an issue with my sequel configuration and reading/saving the response from Snowflake.

I tried add `:encoding => "utf8"` to my `Sequel.odbc(:drvconnect=> SNOWFLAKE_CONN_STR, :encoding => "utf8")` but that didn't change anything.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set below env variables:

```
ENV LANG=en_US.UTF-8
ENV LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8
```

We have this in Dockerfile.